Independent Clause Within Dependent Clause? (CMOS)
Just wondering what exactly Chicago style would say about adding a comma after "and" in this sentence:

They came to the conclusion Susie cheated, as she hadn't studied for the test and the grade she earned was higher than expected.

I'd think to not put a comma because it seems to come in the middle of a subordinated clause, but I'm not sure. I've turned the CMOS upside down and don't have an answer.

You say "Just wondering what exactly Chicago style would say about adding a comma after "and" and then you say " I've turned the CMOS upside down and don't have an answer." Your answer must therefore be "CMOS has nothing to say on the matter." It is therefore an adiaphora. I don't think EL&U is here to second-guess CMOS.

You should explain briefly what relevant things you think CMOS says or doesn't say (give references even) and what the structure of the sentence is: what the clauses are, what the as-clause modifies, etc. (It's not obvious if the as-clause is part of the conclusion or is merely a reason for coming to the conclusion, but you must have an opinion.)

@StuartF I am reading this particular sentence as as independent clause followed by a subordinate clause, with the as-clause function as an explanation as to why they came to their conclusion. I would think adding a comma would make the resulting phrase "as she hadn't studied for the test" seem non-restrictive, though it very much is essential to the sentence.

It flows naturally off the tongue without a comma. He didn't see me as he was behind the house.

as she hadn’t studied for the test is a dependent clause; it does not contain an independent clause. So you can forget about the coordinated independent clauses / comma rule.

Adding a comma after "and" would not be correct. The entire clause

she hadn't studied for the test and the grade she earned was higher than expected.

is the explanation for how they came to the conclusion that she cheated.
If you add the comma, that would mean they came to the conclusion simply because she hadn't studied. "the grade she earned was higher than expected" would be an independent statement.
This isn't really a style choice (like whether to use an Oxford comma), it's one of the ways commas are normally used to group clauses. So it may not be in CMOS. It might be in CGEL. I don't have either, so I can't check.
